# storing the values from one char array to another char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I wrote this code:

```
shuffledteamnames[8][80]; // global
winningteamnames[8][80]; // global
int main()
{
    if (team1 > team2)
    {
        cout << shuffledteamnames[index1] << " beat the " << shuffledteamnames[index2] << " " << team1 << "-" << team2 << " in a game 1." << endl;
        winningteamnames[WINTEAMcounter] = shuffledteamnames[index1];
    }
    else if (team1 < team2) // index1 = 0, index2 = 1, WINTEAMcounter = 0
    {
        cout << shuffledteamnames[index2] << " beat the " << shuffledteamnames[index1] << " " << team1 << "-" << team2 << " in a game 1." << endl;
        winningteamnames[WINTEAMcounter] = shuffledteamnames[index2];
    }
}
```

The output of `shuffledteamnames` is something like this:

```
Trojans
Bruins
Bears
Trees
Ducks
Beavers
Huskies
Cougars
```

I am trying to create a competition bracket where I take the winners of each round and place them into char array `winningteamnames`. I understand that these are 2D char arrays so I need to input data into both parameters, but I'm just not sure how to do that. Please let me know if I was vague at any point and I really appreciate all the help.

Comment: Are you missing the `char` type in your declarations of the team name arrays? Why don't you use `std:string`

Comment: we arent allowed to use strings or vectors

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy

Comment: would it matter if it was a 2d array though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strncpy()`:

```
strncpy( winningteamnames[WINTEAMcounter]
       , shuffledteamnames[index1]
       , sizeof winningteamnames[WINTEAMcounter]);
```

Comment: okay, using strncpy gives me an error footballA2.cpp:290:70: error: too few arguments to function ‘char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)’
   strncpy(winningteamnames[WINTEAMcounter], shuffledteamnames[index1]);
                                                                      ^
In file included from footballA2.cpp:4:0:
/usr/include/string.h:131:14: note: declared here
 extern char *strncpy (char *__restrict __dest,
              ^

and when i use strcpy it only stores the value when WINTEAMcounter is 1, 2, or 3, but not 0. Is there any other information that would help debug this?

Comment: It should work with any value of `WINTEAMcounter` from 0 to 7. You haven't shown enough of your program to explain why there's any difference.